# how to add enum fields at runtime in Java

Tags: java, enums

How can you add enum fields such as `HIGH(1)`, `MEDIUM(2)`, `LOW(3)` at runtime in Java?

```
public enum Status {
    HIGH,
    MEDIUM,
    LOW;  
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you are in need to change the value at runtime, don't use an ENUM use another structure as a class with setter methods or whatever.

Comment: You don't. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Best to assume it can't be done and move on.

Comment: I am trying to get the user input data from the web page and store this somewhere but not to database and use this data to other webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to do this is by using reflection.

For an example see here:

http://www.jroller.com/VelkaVrana/entry/modify_enum_with_reflection

The guts doing the work is this method:

```
/** 
 * <b>Experimental and too much related to internal java implementation - use on your own risk</b> 
 */  
public static void setStaticFieldValue(final Class beanClass, final String fieldName,  
                                       final Object newValue) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {  
    // TODO: find some better way how to change static field  
    Field field = getField(beanClass, fieldName);  
    boolean accessible = field.isAccessible();  

    field.setAccessible(true);  
    try {  
        FieldAccessor fieldAccessor = (FieldAccessor) invokeMethod(field, "getFieldAccessor", new Class[]{  
                Object.class  
        }, new Object[]{  
                beanClass  
        });  

        Object isReadOnly = getFieldValue(fieldAccessor, "isReadOnly");  
        try {  
            setFieldValue(fieldAccessor, "isReadOnly", false);  

            //field.set(beanClass, newValue);  
            fieldAccessor.set(beanClass, newValue);  
        } finally {  
            setFieldValue(fieldAccessor, "isReadOnly", isReadOnly);  
        }  
    } finally {  
        field.setAccessible(accessible);  
    }  
}
```

You really shouldn't have to modify an Enum at runtime though. Maybe consider using a Set instead?